# How to get solution from DSolve

Tags: manipulate, expression-manipulation, differential-equations

How to get the solution from DSolve in such way that there is no need to copy the result.

When for example solving:

```
f[x_, y_] := a y + x^2
 DSolve[{D[y[x], x] == f[x, y[x]], y[0] == c}, y[x], x]
```

I get the solution:

```
{{y[x] -> (-2 + 2 E^(a x) + a^3 c E^(a x) - 2 a x - a^2 x^2)/a^3}}
```

How can I make a function of this let's say sol[x] so I can use it in such context:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 5}], {a, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5}]
```

EDIT: not interested in:

```
sol[x_, a_, c_] = 
 y[x] /. DSolve[{D[y[x], x] == f[x, y[x]], y[0] == c}, y[x], x]
```

Comment: You mean [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue.html?q=DSolveValue)?

Comment: Not really, as Manipulate does not work with it as well. I can always stay with sol[x_,a_,c_] version. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, then have you considered `DSolveValue[……] (* start a new line *) Manipulate[Plot[%, {x, 0, 5}], {a, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5}]`?

Comment: @xzczd Why do not you give this as an answer?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Because I'm not sure if this is what OP wants , `%` is surely not a _function_ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add a bit to the  xzczd answer given in a form of a comment above. In earlier Mma versions (that might be your case) it can be done as follows:

```
    f[x_, y_] := a y + x^2
ss = DSolve[{D[y[x], x] == f[x, y[x]], y[0] == c}, y, x][[1, 1]]
```

yielding this:

```
(*  y -> Function[{x}, (-2 + 2 E^(a x) + a^3 c E^(a x) - 2 a x - a^2 x^2)/
  a^3]    *)
```

Then you can Manipulate/Plot it using the following construct:

```
    Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. ss /. {a -> a1, c -> c1}], {x, 0, 5}], {a1, -5,
   5}, {c1, -5, 5}]
```

Have fun!