# Plot showing up blank when I define expression outside of Manipulate

Tags: plotting, function-construction, manipulate

I obtain an expression through various steps using the differentiate and solve tools, and then I would like to plot it using Manipulate. However, due to how the expression was obtained I would like to define the expression outside of Manipulate. If I define the expression inside of Manipulate it works fine.

This gives a blank plot:

```
RHSLambdaPrime = expression1
RHSSPrime = expression2

Manipulate[
 Module[{fncts, vars, eq, data, sol},
  fncts = {\[Lambda], S};
  vars = {t, 0, T};
  eq = {\[Lambda]'[t] == RHSLambdaPrime, 
        S'[t] == RHSSPrime};
  data = {\[Lambda][T] == 0,
    S[0] == s};

  sol = DSolve[{eq, data}, fncts, vars];

  Show[{
    Plot[Evaluate[Through[fncts[t]] /. sol], Evaluate@vars, 
     PlotLegends -> fncts]
    }, ImageSize -> Large]
  ], {{a, 0.1}, 0, 1}, {{b, 0.2}, 0, 0.4}, {c, 0, 50}, {{m, 200}, 1, 
  1000}, {{\[Tau], 50}, 50, 200}, {{\[Delta], 0.4}, 0, 1}, {{s, 100}, 
  0, 500}, {{T, 10}, 1, 19}, {r, 0.01, 0.1}, {{\[Alpha], 1}, 0, 
  10}, {{\[Beta], 1}, 0, 10}]
```

How can I pass RHSLambdaPrime to Manipulate properly?

Comment: It is a scoping issue. The control variables are local to the `Manipulate`, they need to be passed to the function. 

`f[a_, b_, x_] = a x + b; 

Manipulate[Plot[f[a, b, x], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 7}, {b, 0, 7}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you, that worked! However, I am unsure how to apply it to my actual problem. I store the result of various computations into a variable called RHS (which is composed of various functions and parameters).

Comment: Post a new question with a minimal example which is closer to what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @BobHanlon I edited my question to show what I mean, let me know if that clarifies things

Comment: You have been told that the external functions (RHSLambdaPrime , RHSSPrime) need to be parameterized so that the control variables can be passed to the functions. You have made no attempt to do that. Until you do, the control variables will not be seen by the external functions.

Comment: @BobHanlon Like this?

`RHSLambdaPrime[\[Lambda][t],S[t]] = expression1`
I am still encountering the same issue when I define it this way

Comment: For instance, if `expression1` is dependent on the control variables `a`, `b`, and `c` then define it as `RHSLambdaPrime[a_, b_, c_] = expression1`. And inside the `Manipulate` when you use `RHSLambdaPrime` you would need to include the control variables like `RHSLambdaPrime[a, b, c]`. Just like was shown for `f` in your first example. See [`"Defining Functions"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html)

Comment: A common approach is use `DSolve` or `ParametricNDSolve` before the `Manipulate` and then plot the solution in the `Manipulate`.  The answer to [How to get solution from DSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56282/how-to-get-solution-from-dsolve) shows an easy way to plot the solution obtained before the `Manipulate`.  Do a keyword search of this forum for good examples of other approaches.