# how to use subscripted variable such as a_i as the control of Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, scoping, variable-definitions, variable, subscript

I'd like to define a series of variables called $l_1$,$l_2$, etc., in Mathematica, using the "ctrl+_" shortcut. Moreover, I want to use these variables as the controls of a Manipulate[] function so that I can see how an expression is affected by the change of these variables.

Somehow it seems that Manipulate can't take controls containing Subscripts (as far as I remember, I encountered this issue before so I guess this is the case). For example, in the following code, "h" is recognized as a control which is displayed with a different color; on the other hand, the variables containing subscripts won't be recongnized.

```
Manipulate[{ListLinePlot[
   Labeled[ {Subscript[A, 0], Subscript[A, 11], Subscript[A, 2], 
     Subscript[A, 3], Subscript[A, 41], Subscript[A, 5]}, 
    "label is:"], Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> Medium]}, {{Subscript[l, 0], 0}, -1, 
  1}, {{Subscript[l, 1], 0.5}, -1, 1}, {{Subscript[l, 2], 0.5}, -1, 
  1}, {{Subscript[l, 3], 0}, -1, 1}, {{Subscript[l, 4], 0.5}, -1, 
  1}, {{Subscript[l, 5], 0.5}, -1, 1}, {{h, 0.5}, -1, 1}]
```

[image: see the different color of the controls in Manipulate[]]

Comment: Subscripted variables lead often to trouble.  Avoid them, use indexed variables. You can still, after the calculations done, change them to subscripted.

Comment: @DanielHuber this is what I have observed, too. I attempted to use subscripts because I have complex internal expressions which I want to see in a neater way, and I thought that there might be some solutions that I'm not aware of.  I'm kind of surprised that this simple task can't be done in Mathematica.

Comment: @larry, I don't understand the example you have provided. You have $l_i$ as variables, but then you show $A_i$. Using `Manipulate[Subscript[l, 0], {Subscript[l, 0], 0, 1}]` works as expected.

Comment: @larry The reason subscripted variables give trouble is that the head of a subscripted variable is not "Variable" but "Subscript". The are therefore no actual variables.

Comment: @Domen The $A_i$  here is defined in advance as functions of $l_i$, which I didn't include here because they are quite complex. However, I realize that you are right in that the subscripted variable can work if the expression within Manipulate[] is a function directly as these variables. However, it won't work if the said expression is not an explicit expression of the subscripted control variable, like in my case. Is there any way to handle this? I mean the expression within Manipulate is defined outside Manipulate

Comment: Your control variables do not appear in the body of the `Manipulate` and the plot values are undefined. Changing the plot argument to `Labeled[{Subscript[l, 0], Subscript[l, 1], h*Subscript[l, 2], Subscript[l, 3], Subscript[l, 4], Subscript[l, 5]}, "label is:"]` works fine. Edit your question to show a minimal example that better reflects what your problem is.

Comment: @BobHanlon now I realize that my problem is not related to subscriptes, but the scope of variables, and I may have to define the expression within Manipulate as an function, as suggested here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216836/plot-showing-up-blank-when-i-define-expression-outside-of-manipulate

Comment: @larry, that is why you should always include all relevant code to the question. If it is too complex, just simplify it. As for the question on using subscripted symbols, it works if you first `Evaluate` your expression ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvq8E.png)).